# Is /Type in Document Catalog of PDF file format really necessary?

Tags: pdf

I have some PDFs for which there is no value for `/Type` in the document catalog.
They have a document catalog like

```
<<
/Pages 3 0 R
/Metadata 4 0 R
>>
```

However https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/pdf-explained/9781449321581/ch04.html says that document catalog (open the link and search keyword 'Document Catalog') that

```
/Type*(Required) Must be /Catalog.
```

But even if this is missing as mentioned above, PDF is getting opened by Acrobat Reader.
So why are such type of PDFs not marked as corrupted even if `/Type` is missing from Document Catalog? Or it is optional?

My problem is that I have to filter out corrupted PDF files. I am using jPod library and that library mark a PDF as corrupted if `/Type` is not equal to `/Catalog` or if it is missing.
Can we remove this check ?

Comment: *My problem is that I have to filter out corrupted PDF files* - what is your definition of "corrupted"? is it "not fulfilling a requirements of the specification" or is it "Adobe Reader complains"?

Comment: @mkl, for our clients if a file can be opened by acrobat reader it is not corrupted. But most of the api throws exception even a pdf can be opened by acrobat as I mentioned, due to various check failure as per PDF specification. So problem is to customize API so that it report only those files corrupted which can not opened by acrobat reader.That is why I am asking can we skip check for /catalog

Comment: You are aware that that is a rapidly moving target? The decision which errors to ignore and which not might change from Adobe Reader version to Adobe Reader version. Even seemingly minor patches may result in formerly accepted documents to be now rejected and vice versa. You had better reject your assignment as invalid.

Answer (score 6):

### Be damned if you are guilty contributing to the general decline of PDF software quality!

According to Table 28 (in chapter 7.7.2 on [page 73 of the official ISO 32000-1 standard as published by Adobe](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/ISO32000/PDF32000-Adobe.pdf#page=81)), the `/Type` entry in the document catalog object clearly is *required*.

*(Also: do not rely on the book you linked to. The book is a good resource, no doubt -- but the official specification of the PDF-1.7 file format is the ISO standard, and the document I linked to above. Always check against the standard -- use your book only to get an easier access to some topics, but do not neglect the official standard!)*

Unfortunately, there are a lot of implementations out there which do not complain about b0rken PDF files, and which open the file without notifying the user or developer about any problems encountered. They silently "repair" these files, but they do not inform the users about this. Adobe Acrobat software is amongst those guilty of this behaviour.

This is bad, ***extremely bad even!***, because it encourages other developers and implementors of the PDF file format to become equally sloppy.

The end result is: all PDF producing software will degenerate in quality. It will open more and more weak spots that can be exploited by the "bad guys" in the future.

Don't be like that -- keep your check in place! ***If you don't, you're becoming guilty contributing to the general decline of PDF software quality.***

***Be damned if you are!***

Comment: It has been a long-time understanding that a well-behaving PDF viewer tries to display as much as possible, and tries to repair what is repairable. And we now have to live with crappy PDF. There is (at the moment) also no ISO 32000 validator out there (I read about something being developed, but that may still take some time to become available). Until then, we depend on the honesty and experience of the developers.

Comment: @MaxWyss: It's ok to repair what is repairable, and display as much as possible. It's not ok to do that in complete silence! It's not ok to pretend that the file was fine if it wasn't! But that's what Adobe is doing since years, and they were too stubborn to change this behavior, even when they were begged to do so.

Comment: Usually you'll see: - PDF deviating from spec - Bug report to developer of creator software - Comment from developer: "Adobe Reader displays the file just fine so there can't be anything wrong with it." - WONTFIX

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: What is your intention? Finger-pointing at a dumb developer or viewing the PDF? To extend the expressed opinion, you would also not accept any error-correcting mechanism anywhere…

Comment: @user2543253: Even now, with ISO 32000, there are no strict specs, and there is room for interpretation. And, as said, there is no (ISO-certified) PDF validator out there. For long times, and still now, Adobe Acrobat/Reader has been the standard; if it can display it, it is good, if it can not, it is broken. Maybe one day, when there will be a ISO-certified PDF validator, you may have something at hand to get after the developer of the PDF creating software.

Comment: @MaxWyss: Because you ask, and because I seem to not have been comprehensible enough -- I want ***both***:  (1) view the PDF, and (2) have the viewer software clearly point at all auto-corrections it had to make. ***I want a switch in Adobe's and other's PDF software that enables such warnings, and that even enables bailouts in case of errors.***

Comment: @MaxWyss: And could you please refrain from extending other peoples' expressed opinions, OK? Thank you.

Comment: @MaxWyss: question of an obviously noobie PDF developer was *"Is /Type in DocumentCatalog required?"* and your comment is *"there are no strict specs"* ?!? Don't you see what you are perpetrating? ***You*** should know better!