# A very weird pdf document: only half visible in Adobe reader

Tags: pdf

I found a very weird PDF document here:

[This is the PDF document](http://att.newsmth.net/att.php?p.99.179348.388.pdf)

When opening it in Adobe reader, only half of the contents are visible; while if I change to SumatraPDF reader, then all the contents are visible.

What is happening to this document? and how can I fix it so that it is normal in Adobe reader?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acrobat X says 'an error exists on this page...' which is why only half of it is visible. It draws up to the point where the error occurs.

SumatraPDF is based on MuPDF and clearly MuPDF is simply more tolerant of this particular class of broken PDF file. Acrobat is normally quite tolerant and doesn't even bother to issue warnings most of the time, sadly.

Ghostscript gives me 2 warnings; first that it expected a number and didn't get one, so it replaced it with 0, and second that an invalid shading was ignored.

The actual problem is the shading dictionary in object 90:

```
90 0 obj
<<
  /BBox [ 0.0260000005 0.467999995 0.973999977 ]
```

Bounding Boxes are required to have 4 values and this one only has 3, so its not valid.

Its not easy to fix a PDF file, the best solution is to make it afresh with a fixed tool. The file is compressed, so you'll need to decompress it before you can modify it, then you'll have to guess what the missing value ought to be.

Comment: Actually, Acrobat/Reader are getting less and less tolerant to defective PDFs; an old version of Acrobat (let's say Acrobat 7 or even 5) may be able to display the document properly, and then there is a chance that it can be kind of healed by resaving.

Comment: @MaxWyss *Actually, Acrobat/Reader are getting less and less tolerant to defective PDFs* ... and that is good!

Comment: @MaxWyss: "*Actually, Acrobat/Reader are getting less and less tolerant to defective PDFs*"... and I'd like to think that my continual campaigning on this topic **[(see also here)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27483183/359307)** helped to push things into this direction :-)

Comment: Dunno if your 'privilege' is sufficient to vote upon (or even *see*) this question here, but... **["2 more votes from other users are needed to undelete this question"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12620113/359307).** (Thx!)

Comment: @mkl: Well, yes, sure, it is good. OTOH, what can the innocent user do to get his document opened to at least make a healthy copy…

Comment: @Max *what can the innocent user do to get his document opened to at least make a healthy copy…* - he can ask his document source to *provide* a healthy copy.

Comment: @mkl …if the document source still exists…